# WriteLine not printing all the text

Tags: c#, .net, console.writeline

I am working on a c# program that is extracting useful data to a flat file.

The data in the source is in this format :

---

Subject: Daily Alarm

Reach: Global

type: weekly
date: 04/05/2012 16.03.03
amount: 388

type: weekly
date: 04/05/2012 16.03.03
amount: 567

---

The output should contain these as two rows:

---

```
Daily Alarm|Global|weekly|05042012160303|388
Daily Alarm|Global|weekly|05042012160303|567
```

---

I am done with the coding and Console.WriteLine is printing the required output

But when I use

```
System.IO.StreamWriter output = new System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\\SHARPE\\multirow\\destination.txt");
```

output.WriteLine is yielding a result like this

---

```
Daily Alarm|Global|weekly|05042012160303|388
Daily Alarm|Globa
```

---

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You'll probably need a longer code snippet showing everything you do with the `output` object.

Comment: You'll have to show more code, but I bet you're not correctly closing the streamwriter. Try instantiating it inside a using block (`using (var output = new System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\\SHARPE\\multirow\\destination.txt")) {  }`), or call `output.Flush()` when you're done writing.

Comment: foreach (string keyVal in orderOfValues) 
        { 
         Console.WriteLine(keyVal);
         filecontent += sdValues[keyVal] + "|"; 
        }
        filecontent = filecontent.Replace("<BR>", "");

        Console.WriteLine(filecontent.Substring(0, filecontent.Length - 2));
        output.WriteLine(filecontent.Substring(0, filecontent.Length - 2));

Answer (score 3):

Are you calling StreamWriter.Close() or Flush()?

Edit:

You should always wrap stream writer in using blocks:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"somefile.txt"))
{

}
```

Comment: @downvoter: care to explain? The answer is a valid hint: given the lack of the information in the OP, the most probable reason is failing to close the stream.

Comment: I should say that this was working fine at my home PC where I made it. Both cases Framework 2